# How to get the arguments of an advised function?

Tags: elisp, advice

After my initial config, `ido-read-internal` becomes advised by `flx`:

```
(ido-mode)
(require 'flx-ido)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

So now I get this:

```
(help-function-arglist 'ido-read-internal t)
;; => (&rest rest)
```

instead of this:

```
(help-function-arglist 'ido-read-internal t)
;; => (item prompt hist &optional default require-match initial)
```

I've found a small work around for this:

```
(ad-deactivate 'ido-read-internal)
(help-function-arglist 'ido-read-internal t)
(ad-activate 'ido-read-internal)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Are there any side-effects of
calling `ad-deactivate` and `ad-activate`?

Comment: I think this can be considered a bug, so please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Stefan, bug report sent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ad-get-orig-definition` to get the original definition and then use `help-function-arglist` as usual to get the argument list, for example

```
(help-function-arglist (ad-get-orig-definition 'ido-read-internal))
```